# reducing the halting problem to the blank tape problem

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, halting-problem

I have checked many discussions for understanding this problem.

I understand the reasoning , unfortunately there are some drawback in my understanding.

**The Blank-tape halting Problem**

**Input**: Turing Machine M

**Question** : Does M halt when started with a blank tape?

So this is the reduction :

[image]

The construction of Mw is as follows :

- When started on blank tape, writes w
- Then continues execution like M

What i don't undesstand is the step 2 , in my opinion if we execute M on w maybe M will loop !!!

My second question : what the blank-tape do when executed?even if the blanktape machine halt on blank tape , how can we be sure that M halt on w .i miss something here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should define in your post the Blank-tape problem for completeness.

Comment: The "blank-tape halting problem decider" is something which you assume to exist, capable of always providing the correct YES/NO answer. The transformation should make it so that $M_w$ halts on the blank tape **if and only if** $M$ halts on $w$, i.e. these problems become equivalent. Your drawing shows how this gives you a halting problem decider, which you **know** doesn't exist. Thus you've reached a contradiction, so the assumption was wrong and the blank-tape decider doesn't exist either.

Comment: Please avoid using pictures, try to describe the reduction in the post to avoid dependency on external resources.

Comment: I will edit my Post after reading the awnsers , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blank-tape Halting problem, given a Turing machine $\langle M \rangle$, asks whether or not $M$ eventually halts when starts from the empty tape, i.e, its input is the empty string.

It is a decision problem that returns "YES" or "NO". Thus the decider for the Blank-tape Halting problem is another Turing machine $M_{D}$ that takes as input a Turing machine $\langle M \rangle$ (its description) and returns "YES" or "NO" (prints "YES" or "NO" and halts).

Reducing the Halting problem to the Blank-tape Halting problem means that the we should construct a decider for the Halting problem using the decider for the Blank-tape Halting problem. We could construct it as following.

```
HP-decider(M,w)
  1) generate a TM M' which starts from the empty tape
     then writes w on its tape and runs on w
  2) result = BTHP-decider(M')
  3) if result == "YES" then return YES
  4) if result == "NO" then return NO 
end
```

It is not hard to see that $M'$ halts iff $M(w)$ halts.

In fact you don't need to simulate $M$ on $w$. You don't care about how `BTHP-decider(M')` works/decides either. What you must show is that the Halting problem is solvable using the Blank-tape Halting problem.

Comment: 3) if result == "YES"  means that M' halt on empty tape . i don't understand how we can deduce from here that M halt on w.sorry but a lot of confusion in my head.

Comment: Yes, `result == "YES"` means that M' halts on empty tape. `BTHP-decider(M')` decides whether or not $M'$ halts. ($M'$ is $M_w$ in your post). What does $M'$ ( or $M_w$) do? It starts from the empty tape and writes down "its own input $w$" and then runs on $w$, kind of $M(w)$.

Comment: do you mean that the blank tape decider execute M on w and sees if it halts or no ?

Comment: Not exactly. It decides if $M'$ (or $M_w$) halts. But $M_w$ halts iff $M(w)$ halts, since what $M_w$ does is starts from the empty tape, writes $w$ on the tape and runs on $w$ equivalently to  $M(w)$. But we do not know how the empty blank halting problem decider works, and in fact we don't care about it. What is important its response: "YES" or "NO".

Comment: So the key idea is M' , its execution is starting from empty input , writing w on its tape , and  execute . as the decider get M' with the blank tape  it can decide that our M' halt or not........

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I think that i get the idea , how hard it was in the begining.i have to thank you for your kidness and patience , hopefully we have such humans in this world.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction does not actually execute $M$, what its actually doing is the following mapping:

$\big(\langle M\rangle,w\big)\mapsto \langle M_w\rangle$

Where $M_w$ is the machine that when executed with blank tape, simulates the machine $M$ on input $w$. Preforming the reduction does not require that you execute $M$, you simply need to write down the code of $M_w$. Obviously $M$ halts on $w$ iff $M_w$ halts when executed with blank tape (we constructed $M_w$ specifically for this purpose), and the correctness of the reduction follows.

Comment: do you mean by 'simulates the machine M on input w' ---> exuting M on w?is <M> = <Mw>?

Comment: Yes to the first question, the term simulation is often used when we talk about a new computation which mimics some other given computation, e.g. a Universal Turing machine is able to execute (simulate) any given machine. $\langle M\rangle$ is a notation for the encoding of the machine $M$, since $M$ and $M_w$ are different machines, they have different encodings.

Comment: can i say that Mw is the encoding of M followed by the word w?

Comment: No. $M_w$ is a new machine, which has $M,w$ hardcoded into it. This is analogous to having a new function $g$ in your favorite programming language using the code of some other function $f$. I suggest that you go over the basics again, perhaps by following some book/course notes, and review your question again after you have done so.

Comment: thank you ariel , next week i will have an exam , unfortunatly this part is very hard for me , i'm trying to understand some problem.thank you very much , i think i get the trick.....